# Cakephp find count group by in view

Tags: cakephp, count, group-by, find

I have a model Gameline and controller GamelinesController and database 'gamelines'.
I want to run this query

[image]

Which means there is one record belongs to  2013-02-18 and there is two records belong to 2013-02-25.

After that how to loop count that belongs to each g_time field in view Please help me.

Comment: Please share your (Cake)PHP code. Because the query you have in your screenshot is not the query you run in your application. Because you make use of the CakePHP method (I suppose). So can you paste your code please? And your results?

Comment: $date_count = $this->Gameline->find('count',
   array(
    'fields' => 'Gameline.g_time',
    'group' => 'Date(`g_time`)',
   )
  );
  $this->set('game_counts', $date_count);

Comment: Please update your OP with that.

Comment: I need just how to loop find('count') in view by foreach. I need only this. <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?><?php echo $row['Gameline']['g_time']; ?><?php echo $row['Count']; ?><?php endforeach; ?> In there I can display g_time field but I cannot display Count field

Comment: As I said earlier. Please update your OP. Because the code you are posting in the comments isn't readable at all. I don't want to decode it first. Please update your question. People who are going to answer your question want a question which is as easy as possible for them. You have to put in some effort, not us.

Answer (score 1):

For fields using MySQL functions, like `DATE()`. You can use [Virtual Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html). In your case, you would add something like this to your Gameline model:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields = array(
        'date' => 'DATE(' . $this->alias . '.g_time)'
    );
}
```

That way, the formatted date will be available as the virtual field `date` (use another name if you already have a field that's called like that).

Then in your `find()` operation, fetch the new virtual `date` field. In order to output those results to your view, you can simply loop over your resultset. Let's say you store your `find()` result in a view parameter called `$data`, then you would display the table like:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['Gameline']['date']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Gameline']['count']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```